# Error:- getting error while getting registration id for c2dm

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have Written the application for getting registration id for c2dm. but i am getting Exception as unable to start activity component info at line startService(intent);

My main class is

```
 public class IdTestActivity extends Activity {
    static TextView mytext = null;
    Context context = null;
    Intent intent = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
        intent.putExtra("app",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
        intent.putExtra("sender", "dvimayandroid@gmail.com");
        startService(intent);


    }
}
```

My Receiver class is

```
    public class c2dmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.w("C2DM", "Registration Receiver called");
        if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION".equals(action)) {
            Log.w("C2DM", "Received registration ID");
            final String registrationId = intent
                    .getStringExtra("sender");
            String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");

            Log.d("C2DM", "dmControl: registrationId = " + registrationId
                    + ", error = " + error);
            // TODO Send this to my application server
        }
    }

}
```

and my manifest file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.IdTest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application>
        <permission
            android:name="com.IdTest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.IdTest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

        <activity
            android:name=".IdTestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".c2dmReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" >
                </action>

                <category android:name="com.IdTest" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what is the error that you got? add the stack trace of the exception

Comment: 03-20 20:01:54.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1881): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.IdTest/com.IdTest.IdTestActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
03-20 20:01:54.703: E/AndroidRuntime(1881):  at com.IdTest.IdTestActivity.onCreate(IdTestActivity.java:32)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add a permission to your manifest. Check what's needed here, and make sure your app includes everything:

http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#manifest

Answer (score 0):

you should add the permission to reveive messages from C2DM Servers like this in your manifest :

```
 <!-- This app has permission to register and receive message -->
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add the registration intent filter to your service by this you could get the registration id

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="your pacakge" />
        </intent-filter>
```

also you to get the coming registration id you use

```
         intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
```

hope that could help you